# Cannot upload CSV that starts with an integer

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm stuck with what seems like a weird BigQuery bug : I cannot upload a CSV file that starts (first line, first column) by an integer.

Here's my schema : `COL1:INTEGER,COL2:INTEGER,COL3:STRING`

Here's my csv file content :

```
100,4,XXX
100,4,XXX
```

If I put the STRING column as first column, the upload is OK.

If I add a header and tell BigQuery to skip it during the import, the upload is ok too.

But with the CSV and schema above, BigQuery always complains : `Line:1 / Field:1, Value cannot be converted to expected type.`

Anyone knows what the problem is ?

Thank you in advance,
David

Comment: you may use within quotes ("100")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not reproduce this problem--I copied and pasted the content into a file and uploaded it with no problems.

Perhaps the uploaded file format is corrupted somehow?  If there are extra bytes at the beginning of the file, those would be ignored in a header row but might result in this error is the first value of the first field is expected to be an integer.  I'd recommend examining the actual binary data in the file to make sure there's nothing funny going on.

Also, are you doing this import via web UI, command-line tool, or API?  Have you tried one of the other methods?

Comment: Helo jsondit. Actually I was trying with WEB UI.

Comment: Sorry, did not finish my answer : I tried  both Web UI and Java API, with the same result.

Actually you were right, there were a few bytes at the beginning, I think due to UTF8 with/without BOM encoding.

Thank you !